# Getting ntpdate result for scripting

Tags: linux, bash, ntp

I have two NTP servers with different IPs.

I'm trying to make a bash script that synchronizes the system clock with "ntpdate" client.
If first NTP server doesn't respond, my script should try to connect to second NTP server.

I tried to make a system variable called RESULT in this way:
RESULT = ntpdate 192.168.100.41

NTP synchronization works, but when I make an "echo $RESULT", its value is always 0.
So my question is:
Is there a correct way to do this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check execution status stored in `$?`:

```
ntpdate foo.com
17 Feb 12:35:13 ntpdate[16218]: no server suitable for synchronization found
echo $?
1

ntpdate 1.europe.pool.ntp.org
17 Feb 12:36:26 ntpdate[16220]: step time server 109.230.243.8 offset 27.014301 sec
echo $?
0
```

Alternatively, ir you are on Debian, use *ntpdate-debian* and specify server list in */etc/default/ntpdate*, e.g.:

```
NTPSERVERS="0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org"
```

Comment: Or, more succinctly, `ntpdate server1 || ntpdate server2`. Isn't `ntpdate` by itself able to fall back to a different server? Just configure it to use your two servers.